# Javascript context menu to C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, contextmenu

I have created a javascript context menu using Jquery that works perfectly. But there are two options. The first one is to create this context menu in C# (If that's possible). The second way is to run a C# Function when a button in the menu is clicked. Which option is the best and how do i start? Kind regards

**Javascript:**

```
function Menu($div){
    var that = this, 
        ts = null;

    this.$div = $div;
    this.items = [];

    // create an item using a new closure 
    this.create = function(item){
      var $item = $('<div class="item '+item.cl+'">'+item.label+'</div>');
      $item
        // bind click on item
        .click(function(){
          if (typeof(item.fnc) === 'function'){
            item.fnc.apply($(this), []);
          }
        })
        // manage mouse over coloration
        .hover(
          function(){$(this).addClass('hover');},
          function(){$(this).removeClass('hover');}
        );
      return $item;
    };
    this.clearTs = function(){
      if (ts){
        clearTimeout(ts);
        ts = null;
      }
    };
    this.initTs = function(t){
      ts = setTimeout(function(){that.close()}, t);
    };
  }

  // add item
  Menu.prototype.add = function(label, cl, fnc){
    this.items.push({
      label:label,
      fnc:fnc,
      cl:cl
    });
  }

  // close previous and open a new menu 
  Menu.prototype.open = function(event){
    this.close();
    var k,
        that = this,
        offset = {
          x:0, 
          y:0
        },
        $menu = $('<div id="menu"></div>');

    // add items in menu
    for(k in this.items){
      $menu.append(this.create(this.items[k]));
    }

    // manage auto-close menu on mouse hover / out
    $menu.hover(
      function(){that.clearTs();},
      function(){that.initTs(3000);}
    );

    // change the offset to get the menu visible (#menu width & height must be defined in CSS to use this simple code)
    if ( event.pixel.y + $menu.height() > this.$div.height()){
      offset.y = -$menu.height();
    }
    if ( event.pixel.x + $menu.width() > this.$div.width()){
      offset.x = -$menu.width();
    }

    // use menu as overlay
    this.$div.gmap3({
      action:'addOverlay',
      latLng: event.latLng,
      content: $menu,
      offset: offset
    });

    // start auto-close
    this.initTs(5000);
  }

  // close the menu
  Menu.prototype.close = function(){
    this.clearTs();
    this.$div.gmap3({action:'clear', name:'overlay'});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could create a server control in C# and emit the menu from it, but since you already have a working menu it's just easier to call a server-side method in response to a click. If you're using jQuery it's as easy as:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Path/To/MyMethod",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: <some POST data>,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        // Do your stuff here
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Report error
    }
});
```

The implementation of the server-side part can be either a static [WebMethod] in an ASPX page, or if you're using MVC then it can be a direct call to a controller method.

Comment: Im not using MVC. Am i being rude if i'll ask you to implement your code with mine? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming what you are trying to do is call a c# method when an Item on the context menu is selected. If you are using an MVC model this is pretty easy to do. Use a call as follows passing the parameters in JSON format. I am just using a skeleton method from my code as an example you would call LibraryRead method when you click on the Context Menu Link

```
 Client Side

 function LibraryRead() {   
    $.ajax({
        url : 'Library/ReadLibrary',
        type : "POST",
        data : JSON.stringify(idLibrary),
        dataType : "json",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success : function(result) {
            $(result).each(function() {
                ....Process Results
            });
        },
        error : function() {
            .....If something goes wrong, if you use a try catch in your code 
            which does not handle the exception correctly and something goes wrong 
            this will not be triggered. Use propper exception handling.
        }
    });
}



Server Side 

// Post: /Library/ReadLibrary
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ReadLibrary(int idLibrary)
{
    try
    {

        var library = READ your library here from your data source

        return this.Json(library);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Exception handling omitted for simplicity
    }
}
```

Do a search on google for MVC3 and JQuery / Javascript calls with JSON, there are loads of resources available.

If you are not using MVC pattern you may be able to use a web service or method in the code behind. You need to add the appropriate attribute over the method though like [Ajax.AjaxMethod()] or [WebMethod]

Comment: Im not using MVC. Am i being rude if i'll ask you to implement your code with mine? ;)